# How do you find the steady periodic solution of this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, steady-state

Find the steady state periodic solution of the differential equation: $$ y^{''}+16y = f(t)$$

where $f(t)$ is an odd function of period $2\pi$ such that $$f(t) = t $$ $$ 0 \leq t < \pi $$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I understand how to generally solve this type of problem when there is no resonance. The part I am stuck on is I understand there is resonance in this problem since the complimentary solution has a sin(4t) term and so does the right hand side fourier series. I am not sure how to proceed when resonance occurs

Answer (score 0):

There is no periodic solution.  All solutions of the differential equation have $y((2n+1)\pi) = y((2n-1)\pi) + \pi/8$.